# How to delete a row from react-virtualized?

Tags: react-virtualized

**What is the best way to delete a row from InfiniteLoader so that when the row is deleted the gap should automatically fill by remaining rows?**

[image]
[image]

[image]

And my render function look like this

```
render() {
   let { msgList } = this.state;
   let listSize = !msgList.length ? 1 : msgList.length + 1;

return (
  <div className="section msgCont">
        <InfiniteLoader isRowLoaded={this.isRowLoaded} loadMoreRows={this.loadMoreRows} rowCount={listSize}>

          {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (

            <AutoSizer className="card-container">
              {({ height, width }) => (

                <List
                  ref={registerChild}
                  onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                  width={width}
                  height={height}
                  rowCount={listSize}
                  rowHeight={150}
                  rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
                />
              )}
            </AutoSizer>
          )}
        </InfiniteLoader>
  </div>
);
```

}

**Solution

Now I got the solution, by just simply update your message list with removed index, all works perfectly fine, earlier i have do the same but due to some code error not works well.

```
onCrossButtonClick = (index) => {
   let list = this.state.msgList;
   this.setState({
     msgList: [...list.slice(0,index) , ...list.slice(index+1,list.length)]
   });
}
```

Comment: did you found a solution for this? I have the same issue. Thanks

Comment: I have already updated the solution please read again the solution part ->   By just simply update your message list with removed msg index.

Comment: It is working only because your row have same height. This solution does'nt work for dynamic row height. At componentWillReceiveProps I reorder the cache (deletion/addition) but the scrollTop keep bullying me :'(.